# How can I build an array of column D where column A = Arg

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

"Entries" is a sheet that I enter individual tasks with the date, name, start time, end time.  It calculates total time per task
"Days" is a generated sheet that gets dates from Entries and calculates total time worked on all tasks for each unique day in Entries

I would like Days to have a column that uses the date from column A, looks in Entries, and returns the earliest start time from any row in Days that is for that date.

```
    function startTime(theDate) {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var ent = ss.getSheetByName("Entries");
        ent.activate();
        var rng = ent.getRange(rownumber, 1, 1, numberofcolums)
        var rangeArray = rng.getValues();
    }
```

calling using :

=startTime(A1)

where A1 contains the Date that I want the check-in time for.

Comment: The likely reason someone has already marked this post to be closed is that there isn't enough information. You've just dropped a piece of code out of context. What you are trying to do can *probably* be accomplished with formulas instead of script. But in any case, there isn't much anyone can tell you without seeing the *actual data* in context. Consider sharing a link to the spreadsheet or to a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

#### The array of columnA where A = 'Arg'

```
function colDWhereAisArg() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let o = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,4).getValues().map(r => {
    if(r[0] == 'Arg') {
      return [r[3]];
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}

Execution log
4:29:59 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:30:00 PM  Info    [[5],[8],[13]]
4:30:00 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

My Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Arg | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| Arg | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Arg | 11 | 12 | 13 |